# Не работает модуль Likedislike

Tags: yii

```
POST http://localhost/mysite/likedislike/default/likedislike 404 (Not Found)
```

Я беру ссылку проверяю через адресную строку. меняю адрес так:

```
http://localhost/mysite/index.php/likedislike/default/likedislike
```

В окне выводится:
    {"status":false,"count":"0"}

Что надо сделать, чтобы происходило обращение к правильному адресу?

Comment: Я его не юзал, но вы ему передаете какие-нибудь параметры?

http://localhost/mysite/likedislike/default/likedislike?field_id=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давай без слова POST

```
http://localhost/mysite/likedislike/default/likedislike 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost/mysite/index.php/likedislike/default/likedislike
```

Разницу адресов видишь или нет?

файл **index.php** ни о чем не говорит? **Он лишний в строке**.

Comment: вижу, сама вручную добавила index.php, но как мне и что изменить, чтобы обращалось к нужному адресу,а не к http://localhost/mysite/likedislike/default/likedislike ?

Comment: Ну так где ты данные посылаешь там и измени адрес, добавь туда index.php. Проблема то в чем?

Comment: Ну если все настолько плохо, тогда попробуй в конфиге

>'urlManager'=>array('showScriptName'=>false,

Comment: вот я URLmanager пытала=) все. еле нашла в модуле взятого с оф. сайта где торчит этот адрес. спс